# iOS - Autocomplete Using Websockets

Tags: ios, node.js, http, autocomplete, websocket

I'm building an iOS app that allows users to search for books in a large database. We'd like to implement an "autocomplete" feature that retrieves titles from the server as the user is typing, to provide suggestions in a table view (our back end uses ranking algorithms to fetch relevant results).

We're using the [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/starscream) framework to implement Websockets, but I'd like to get some suggestions on the best way to implement this feature. So far I've come up with two options:

1. Open a Websocket connection when the user launches the app, and maintain this connection throughout the whole session. Changes in network connectivity will cause the pipe to be broken, so client-side pinging would need to be used to detect this and establish a new connection.
2. Open a Websocket connection when the user taps in the search bar to begin typing. The connection will remain open only while the search bar is active (while the keyboard is present) and disconnect when the keyboard is dismissed.

One thing to keep in mind is that the app has multiple views and features that do not involve searching, and in fact require connections of their own (for example, a messaging feature currently uses its own Websocket connection to send/receive messages from other users, and other views download content from a REST API). So this leads me to another question:

Are there any disadvantages to maintaining multiple Websocket connections from the same app simultaneously? In addition, what are some good practices that can be used to ensure that the connection(s) stay alive through network transitions (i.e. going from WiFi to cellular)? I've had a lot of issues with this one, particularly with the messaging service.

Any suggestions/help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. For reference, our server uses Node.js with the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) framework for Websockets.

Comment: You might want to take a look at WAMP (protocol) and a WAMP server like http://crossbar.io. This allows you to do multiple things over a single WebSocket connection (I'm on the project team, but this really does sound like a good fit).